# Python script split up

Tags: python, grass.script

I have a python script which works with Grass 6.4. At some point during the project I decided to split this big python script into several scripts. I have made all necessary variables global, created methods, imported scripts in other scripts, etc.

The problem now is that during execution, I get an error on importing grass. More specifically, on "**import grass.script as grass**". This happens in any of the new scripts that have the import line. The strange thing is that I had the same import line in the old script (the big one) and it never failed.

Anyone has any ideas? Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Did you happen to rename or shuffle any directories around when you split the script?

Comment: Actually no. I created several new scripts in the same folder and called them in the primary script. Nothing else is changed. (sorry for the late reply, I thought I would receive a notification when somebody adds a new comment)